# Python 2.7 Pysinstaller with pysftp lib

Tags: python, sftp, pyinstaller

I'm trying to write a very simple SFTP uploading utility that I can deploy to multiple Windows machines so I'd like to compile it as an exe using pyinstaller (I have also tried py2exe).

I am having issues with getting the compilation to work; when I run the .exe after building it, it crashes and gives an error window that says "Failed to execute script".

I assume this has something to do with the pysftp library (only other import in the script is 'os') - does anyone have any suggestions on next steps?

EDIT: I'm thinking there is something off with the lib I am trying to use (potentially how it is installed?). In order to try to circumvent that issue I am now trying to use paramiko directly (which is the lib that pysftp leverages). I get the same exact issue trying to use this lib - Failed to Execute script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. When I try to compile this simple pysftp script with pyinstaller, it seems it is trying to execute the script during the compilation.

```
import pysftp
sftp = pysftp.Connection('1.2.3.4', username = 'username', password = 'password', port = 'port')
#
# ... do sftp operations
sftp.listdir()
#
sftp.close()
test = raw_input('Press enter..')`
```